# Progressive path animation in d3.js: how do I loop over individual elements of a d3 selection, for eg, each path segment of an area chart?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, visualization

I have [this small area chart demo](http://dffrnt.com/d3.html) done in d3.js.

I'm able to animate the chart *as a whole* but can't find a way to animate it piece-by-piece (I want it to be a proper animation, not a simple reveal using svg-clip). For example the code to animate the circles in the page linked above is just 2 simple lines that I've broken up here for clarity:

```
// start frame
chart
    .selectAll( 'circle' )
    .data( data )
    .enter()
    .append( 'circle' )
    .attr( 'cx', function( d, i ) { return x( i ); })
    .attr( 'cy', y( 0 ) )
    .attr( 'class', 'point' ).attr( 'r', 5 );

// end frame
chart
    .selectAll( 'circle' )
    .data( data )
    .transition()
    .duration( 3000 )
    .attr( 'cx', function( d, i ) { return x( i ); })
    .attr( 'cy', function( d, i ) { return y( d ); });
```

The problem here is that ***all*** the circles start and finish at once. The same happens with the segments of the area chart. So how do I move them one after another? One way is to use d3's `delay` function;  I'm not sure how I would do this for the path segments of the area chart but for the circles marking the data points, it'd be something like this:

```
// start frame
chart
    .selectAll( 'circle' )
    .data( data )
    .enter()
    .append( 'circle' )
    .attr( 'cx', function( d, i ) { return x( i ); })
    .attr( 'cy', y( 0 ) )
    .attr( 'class', 'point' ).attr( 'r', 5 );

// end frame
chart
    .selectAll( 'circle' )
    .data( data )
    .transition()
    .delay( 1000 * c )
    .duration( 3000 )
    .attr( 'cx', function( d, i ) { return x( i ); })
    .attr( 'cy', function( d, i ) { return y( d ); });
```

But to do this, I need `c`, the handle linking to individual circles one after the other, as if in a loop.

So my questions are:

1. How do I get `c`, the handle to an individual element of a
   selection, for the circles ***and*** for the area (svg.area()) chart?
2. Is there a simpler way to achieve this than my `delay` approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) The `c` you're looking for can be gotten by passing a function into `delay()`, exactly in the same way you do for any `attr()` call (see [documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions#wiki-delay)):

```
.delay( function(d, i) { return 1000 * i; } )// i is your "c"
```

2) Using `delay()` sure seems like the right approach for this.

AFAIK, you're still going to have difficulties doing the same for the path. I can't come up with any way to do this other than animating the underlying data points themselves.

Comment: The circles were indeed simple, thanks. The `svg.area()` side of things seems to be the real demon now.